# Call HTML page from C# code on condition

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, cookies

I got a page written in c# and a webform written in HTML.

My goal is to show this html webform every time the default.aspx page get loaded ONLY when the cookie are already SET on the client browser. I will set/write the cookie through php from the webform so I assume the c# code just need to:

1. READ THE COOKIE VALUE IF IS SET OT NOT,
2. VISUALIZE OR NOT the html webform depending of the value cookie set.

Not sure if this must be done with c# in code behind or just in javascript.

So, is there any code in C# that allow me to call an HTML page and open it in the same page as a webform/pop-up?
Also, is possible to trigger this html page in the way I can call it only if cookie are set?

```
public partial class Read : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["cookie"] != null)
    {
        ReadCookie();
    }
}

protected void ReadCookie()
{
    //Get the cookie name the user entered
    String strCookieName = Request.QueryString["cookie"].ToString();

    //Grab the cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[strCookieName];

    //Check to make sure the cookie exists
    if (cookie == null)
    {
        lblCookie.Text = "Cookie not found. <br><hr>";   -> SHOW HTML-WEBFORM 
    }
    else
    {

-> DONT SHOW HTML-WEBFORM 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question... "any code in C#" is very vague definition of when/where the code is run. You may be looking for something like SignalR if you need 2-way communication between ASP.Net C# code and web page.

Comment: I ment, from a code written in c# using asp.net

Comment: Not really clarifying.... I assume you've read guidance on [asking questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and decided not to post code for good reason. Unfortunately such decision means you need to have way more detailed explanation of the problem/goal than you'd need if you posted small code sample along with requirement. Please try to explain *when* your "C# code" runs in request lifetime (or maybe it is some timer job or startup code).

Comment: Hope this will work: I got a page written in c# and a webform written in HTML. My goal is to show this html webform everytime the default.aspx page get loaded ONLY when the cookie are already SET on the client browser. I will set/write the cookie through php from the webform so I assume the c# code just need to: 1-READ THE COOKIE VALUE IF IS SET OT NOT, 2 - VISUALIZE OR NOT the html webform depending of the value cookie set. Not sure if this must be done with c# in code behind or just in javascript.

Comment: Please next time edit your post instead of adding details in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check cookies - use `Request.Cookies` collection. You can access cookies by name.

Note that "set/write the cookie through php" may mean cookie is set on different domain - in this case no amount of C# (or any other server side code) will be able to access that cookie and you'll need some non-trivial client side code to make cookie information visible on other domain.

Next when you check for cookie you can render content conditionally by either dynamically adding elements or with conditional code on ASPX page.

Comment: cookie should be set from the server to the client browser.

Comment: aren't this two process separated? the webform is in html and set cookies with php on the webclient browser. The aspx code is going to just read if cookie are set or not into the webclient browser and eventually display or not the webform.

Comment: @bostongeorge "aspx code is going to just read if cookie are set or not " - yes - that is exactly what I suggested.. not sure what your comment is about.

Comment: sorry to not be so clear. You wrote "Note that "set/write the cookie through php" may mean cookie is set on different domain". Is this mean that what I want (set cookie with php with webform and read cookie from aspx/C# code) is not going to work? Else. I don't get the meaning of " cookie is set on different domain ". What do you suggest for my purpose? I have the webform in html and I want it to show or not show based on the condition if cookies are set or not.

Comment: I don't know what you have and you don't care to provide any concrete details, so it is very hard to suggest anything. I assume you understand that when cookie is set it is limited to particular domain(s) and sometimes even particular path on domain. So it is hard for me to guess what you don't understand and what suggestions you are looking for.

Comment: In the form you have 3 choice: 1-"subscribe" (which will send the email to my database and set the cookie variable to TRUE). 2- "don't show this message again" (which will set the cookie variable to TRUE). 3 - "CLOSE" (which will close the form and not set the cookie variable). Note that the database is Linux based,MYsql, so that's why I have to set the cookie variable with PHP. Therefore I want the C# code be able to show this webform everytime the cookie variable is NOT SET. (because if its set means u already subscribed or choose to not show the message again)